# How to make peace after I have what I want

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

**Background**

Another civ founded a city far away from their territory, in the middle of mine, and right where I wanted one. I declared war, quickly took the city, and razed it (mostly because I wanted it moved to the coast). I now want peace, since my empire isn't focused on military.

**Problem**

I offered peace to the other civ, and they refused. I'm not afraid of war, and I'm pretty sure I could beat them, but I'd rather focus on my empire. What can I do to get them to accept peace?

Comment: Row up as much military as you can on their capital, if possible. They will contact you as soon as they think your threat is big enough. Otherwise just protect your borders and sit it out if you can. It is a massive screw over if YOU try to make peace, but if the AI decides to make peace, you get away cheap and sometimes even rich.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The AI will continue to desire war with you until you offer them some enormously advantageous trade deal, or they're fearful that they will lose territory to your military.

Personally, I don't think it's worth it to pay them off, especially if you're in the situation where you think you're stronger than they are.

Luckily, the AI is terrible at war.  Just stick some ranged units (ideally something like Catapults, Trebuchets, Cannons, etc) in your border cities, with some melee units in the hexes towards their border.  They will roll up and get slaughtered, significantly reducing their military might.  Eventually they will come and beg for peace, and offer you something terribly lopsided in return.

If they are distant enough from you, chances are you'll only see a few units or a meager trickle.  In this case, they're never going to get weak enough to offer peace, but they pose such a tiny threat that being at war is not that significant.  Just ride it out, and eventually something will come along that requires their attention.  At that point, they'll probably make an even offer for peace.

Comment: Very informative, thanks! I prepared to go pillage some of their cities. Luckily, they ended up offering peace after I nearly destroyed the only two ships near me (They are on an island on the other side of the world).

Comment: @KendallFrey, yeah, the AI talks big, but loses and/or gets spooked really, really easily :)  They're big babies :P

Answer (score 1):

Moving your units near to one of the enemy's city and then asking for peace usually works for me. Ideally the city to move to should either be capital or otherwise have a big population.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe offer some gold with other things or you could maybe cut off all there roads and just killing out some of there troops.That sometimes makes them want to offer a peace treaty and they might offer some gold.The bad thing is the AI might be stubborn and not accept any peace treaties and you might just have to wipe them out.

Answer (score -1):

Just kill a few more of their troops and they will accept peace. Or you could offer a gift like a unit or gold.